# Does making the plate charged affect the work potential?

Tags: photons, work, photoelectric-effect

Suppose you have a charged plate, Does it being charged affect the work function?

Yes it does create a field around it which eventually will stop any photoelectrons coming out.

My question is, Why it doesn't affect the properties of the metals? Is it because the Electric field inside a metal should always zero so as if nothing happened?

Answer (score 0):

The key reason that charging the plate won't affect the work function is that photons are not charged particles. Yes they are electromagnetic radiation, but they are chargeless particles, therefore the photo electric effect will still take place (assuming that the single difference is the charged plate).

On a separate note: it depends on the charge. Photoelectric effect removes electrons from a metal, if you give the plate a positive charge then it has already lost electrons and therefore it cannot take place.

Comment: Yes it wont affect photons but it will affect the electrons themselves. I am asking whether it will somehow increase the work function or not and why?

Didn't get what u said.